# c# How do I specify a not in a select statement?

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm using a select method on a dataset to retreive the results that match my condition:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsPone2.Tables["tt-pone"].Select(strWhereCondition))
{
    dsPone.Tables["tt-pone"].ImportRow(dr);
}
```

How do I change the strWhereCondition from

```
strWhereCondition += " AND poneid = 0 and aoneid = 0 and tranid = 0";
```

To where tranid is NOT 0?

Do I use `<>` or `!=`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As is so often the case, consulting the documentation is the way forward. `DataTable.Select(string)` redirects to [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) to document what's allowed in a filter expression - and the "Operators" list shows `<>` but not `!=`.

Personally I would try to avoid string-based filtering and use LINQ to DataSet instead, but of course that requires .NET 3.5 or higher.

Comment: Hmm, RTFM, Good idea! To be honest, I've never got on with the C# documentation, I struggle to find what I want. Normally I can get the answer on here quicker. However, next time I have a simple question, I'll try the 'official' papers first. Thanks Jon.

Comment: @Colin: I find that a search for "msdn" along with the name of the member I'm looking for works fine. So in this case I search for "msdn datatable.select". It's *vital* that you learn to navigate the documentation effectively.

Answer (score 4):

you have to use the SQL notation `<>`

in your case `tranid <> 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use `tranid <> 0`.

The syntax for the expressions is [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the [`DataColumn.Expression` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) details the syntax used by the `filterExpression` parameter of the [`DataTable.Select` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx).  In the Operators section about a third of the way down the page it says...

> Concatenation is allowed using Boolean AND, OR, and NOT operators.

...and also lists a `<>` comparison operator.  So, that should mean you can do either `tranid <> 0` or `NOT (tranid = 0)`.