# To select Value From Datatable

Tags: c#

In the below code I have a `datatable` I want to select a value from `datatable` and to check whether value exists or not, but it throws error:

> The best overloaded method match for `System.Data.DataTable.Select(string)` has some invalid argument "," cannot convert from `bool` to `string`

Please help me to solve the issue.

```
Student Details = new Student ();

DataSet ds = Details.Marks();

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

if (dt.Select("RollNo =" != txtRgNo.Text.ToString()) || 
    dt.Select("Name=" != txtName.Text.ToString()))
{
}
else
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTable's "Select()" method uses a filter expression. As a sample you can use the following to query for specific RollNo, and it returns DataRow array. If DataRow returns more than one elements, then it exists. Otherwise, it does not exist.

```
        int rollNumber = 1;
        string filterExpression = string.Format("RollNo = {0}", rollNumber);
        DataRow[] rows = dt.Select(filterExpression);
        if (rows != null && rows.Length > 0)
        {
            //Exists
        }
        else
        {
            //Does not exists
        }
```

A complete filter expression in your case would be like:

```
string filterExpression = string.Format("RollNo <> {0} AND Name <> '{1}'", txtRgNo.Text.ToString(), txtName.Text.ToString());
```

Additional reference to use DataTable.Select():
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When i enter a roll no has E2152 it throws error cannot find column  E2152 in DataRow line

Comment: Can you post your code? It seems that your query is looking for "E2152". If the RollNo is a string, then it should be: "RollNo <> '{0}'"  Take note of the single quote between '{0}'. This means that the value is string not integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Student Details = new Student ();
DataSet ds = Details.Marks();

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

DataRow dr1=dt.Select("RollNo!= " + txtRgNo.Text.ToString());
DataRow dr2=dt.Select("Name !="+  txtName.Text.ToString())
if (dr1.Length>0 ||dr2.Length>0 )
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: it is throws error The best overloaded method match for System.Data.DataTable.Select(string) has some invalid argument "," cannot convert from bool to string

Comment: @MVSE Missed string concatenation

Answer (score 0):

!= should be part of the string filter you are sending to DataTable.Select but it's also not the correct operator to use. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537824/c-sharp-how-do-i-specify-a-not-in-a-select-statement).

Your code should be similar to this:

```
dt.Select("RollNo <> " & txtRgNo.Text.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Linq Queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552415(v=vs.110).aspx) to select and filter any fields like this:

```
Student Details = new Student();

DataSet ds = Details.Marks();

DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var result = from d in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 where d["RollNo"].ToString() == txtRgNo.Text && 
                       d["Name"].ToString() == txtName.Text
                 select new
                 {
                     RollNo = d.Field<int>("RollNo"),
                     Name = d.Field<string>("Name")
                 };

    if (result.Any())
    {
        // results is not empty ...
    }
}
```